# [FPDF][FPDI] How to fix vertical line on top and bottom of a pdf

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to remove top and bottom vertical lines that appear in my pdf pages but I can't find where. In TCPDF, there is method `setPrintHeader()` to change that, but not in FPDF.

My code (if that can help) :

```
$pdf = new Fpdi;
$pdf->setSourceFile($this->internalURL."assets/uploadedContent/*********.pdf");
$page = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($page, 0, 0, null, null);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);

for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', "B", $sizes[$i]);

    if (strlen($textes[$i]) <= $maxChar[$i]) {
        $pdf->SetXY($positionsX[$i], $positionsY[$i]);
        $pdf->Cell(50, 20, $textes[$i], 0, 2);
    } else {
        $indexCut = $maxChar[$i];
        $stop = false;
        while (!$stop) {
            if ($textes[$i][$indexCut] != " ") {
                $indexCut--;
            } else {
                $stop = true;
            }
        }

        $text11 = substr($textes[$i], 0, $indexCut);
        $text12 = substr($textes[$i], $indexCut, strlen($textes[$i]));

        $pdf->SetXY($positionsX[$i], $positionsY[$i]);
        $pdf->Cell(50, 20, $text11, 0, 2);
        $pdf->SetXY(37, $positionsY[$i] + 5);
        $pdf->Cell(50, 20, $text12, 0, 2);
    }

}
```

I tried to remove some part of my code to check where these lines came from but I still don't know.

This is what I get (for example):

[image: Screenshot Result]

Comment: You're simply still using TCPDF.

Comment: Yeah I know, the only solution that I found about that was to turn "setPrintHeader()" to false. But there is no "setPrintHeader()" used in fpdf source code...

Comment: There's also no logic in FPDF that would draw header and footer lines. I still guess, that you are using `\setasign\Fpdi\Tcpdf\Fpdi` instead of `\setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi`.

Comment: How can I check that ? PS : I am using the version 1.6.2 of FPDI (due to my php version)

Comment: `var_dump($pdf instanceof TCPDF);` should do the job.

Comment: I got `bool(true)`. So what should I do to fix that ?

Comment: Use `setPrintHeader()` and `setPrintFooter()` to disable them or uninstall TCPDF. The legacy version of FPDI uses some "magic" under the hood to extend TCPDF if it is available automatically.